# In Telerik Reporting (Desktop), how to inject a json sub-node into sub-report string parameter

Tags: json, report, subreport, telerik-reporting

## Introduction

Based on the below json sample, I am trying to define a **Telerik** report using both a main report and a sub-report, where se second is fed with a subset of the main report json data.

Basically, data flow mimics something like:

1. Application injects base json data into main report's
   **jsonData**(string) parameter;
2. **jsonData** is binded as report datasource;
3. Json data selector is applied;
4. Json selected data **Employes** node is injected into a sub-report, which will also use it as a json data source.

Troubles arose on **step 4**, where I am getting an [**Invalid value of report parameter 'jsonData'**] error when main report is rendered.

It seems **Telerik Report** is unable to convert a selected json node field data into a proper string.

## Full context

For full context:

- **On both reports**:

  - There is a **jsonData** report parameter of **string** datatype;
  - There is a **JsonDataSource** defined;
  - Binding between the string **jsonData** parameter and main **JsonDataSource** is based upon:

    - Property path: **Datasource.Source**
    - Expression: = **Parameters.jsonData.Value**
- **On main report**:

  - JsonDatasource **$.Companies** data selector is being used, resulting in a list representing containing de the companies list, each instance having:
- **Name**, a string representing the company name;
- **Employes**, an object containing the company employes list.

  - Full sample json data is injected thru **jsonData parameter** as a string;
- **On sub-report**:

  - There is also a **jsonData** report parameter of **string** datatype;
  - JsonDataSource **$** data selector is being used, which should result in:

    - A list of the following fields:

      - **Name**, a string representing the name of the employe;
      - **Wage**, a numeric value representing employe's wage.
- **Again on main-report**, I am using the following sub-report parameters mapping:

  - Parameter Name: **jsonData**
  - Parameter Value: **Fields.Employes**
- I am using **Telerik Report Designer v15.1.21.716 (Desktop)**

It seems that data selector converts json **Employes** node date into a **System.Object[]**, which is giving me a nice hard time figuring out how to convert it back to a json string.

I have alread extensively searched on documentation, web, ChatGPT and alikes for a valid solution. So far, no luck.

## Before you help me

Although I have the most appreciation for anyones effort trying to helping me:

- I am pursuing a json only data source solution. I mean, I am not interested on any other alternative suported Telerik Reporting datasources;
- Solution must work in both design-time and runtime.

```
{
    "Companies": [
        {
            "Name": "Company1",
            "Employes": [
                {
                    "Name": "Joe",
                    "Wage": 1000
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Jack",
                    "Wage": 2000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Company2",
            "Employes": [
                {
                    "Name": "Mary",
                    "Wage": 3000
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Mike",
                    "Wage": 4000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, passing the "Employes" object to the "jsonData" parameter of the subreport should not work because the object cannot be converted to a JSON string directly. You have to convert it thru **CStr()** function.

However, instead of using a parameter to set the data source of the subreport, you can use the binding described in the [How to Represent Hierarchical Nested Data](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/hierarchical-report-from-nested-data?_gl=1*21756n*_ga*MjA1OTU1NTYwOC4xNjgxODI2NDkz*_ga_9JSNBCSF54*MTY4NjExODE4Ni4zNy4xLjE2ODYxMjQyNjkuNjAuMC4w#solution-1) KB article.

I also want to mention that in the [R3 2022 SP1](https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/reporting/release-history/progress-telerik-reporting-r3-2022-sp1-16-2-22-1109?_gl=1*1porloh*_ga*MjA1OTU1NTYwOC4xNjgxODI2NDkz*_ga_9JSNBCSF54*MTY4NjExODE4Ni4zNy4xLjE2ODYxMjQ1MzIuNjAuMC4w) release, the DataSource property was added to the SubReport item as well. This makes the approach I suggested above obsolete because it allows you to bind the data source of the subreport directly in the main report.
For example:

## Solution 1

### SubReport item binding based on DataSource property:

```
Property path: DataSource

Expression: = Fields.Employes
```

## Solution 2

In @Julio's provided sample, which allows to inject json node as a sub-report parameter, instead of a direct datasource, you should use following approach.

### **SubReport item binding thru sub-report parameter:**

```
Property path: jsonData

Expression: = CStr(Fields.Employes)
```

### Bear in mind that...

- **Solution 1**, does not require explicit inner sub-report binding to datasource;
- **Solution 2**, requires additional binding between the sub-report
  parameter and its datasource, as stated on the original post.

For further details on this subject, check original [Telerik's original post](https://www.telerik.com/forums/in-telerik-reporting-desktop-how-to-inject-a-json-sub-node-into-sub-report-string-parameter)